# how to find out days from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE   @Daystaken TABLE(
Application VARCHAR(20),
StatusId VARCHAR(2),
Flag INT,
Createddate Datetime)

INSERT INTO @Daystaken (CreatedDate)VALUES
('2015-03-06 17:59:59.410'),
('2015-03-02 17:59:59.410')
select DATEDIFF(DD,MIN(CreatedDate),GETDATE())D from @Daystaken

DECLARE   @holiday TABLE(holiday Datetime)

INSERT INTO @holiday (  holiday )VALUES
(   '2014-04-06 17:59:59.410'),
(   '2014-06-06 17:59:59.410'),
(   '2015-05-05 17:59:59.410'),
(   '2015-05-01 17:59:59.410'),
(   '2013-01-06 17:59:59.410'),
(   '2015-02-03 17:59:59.410'),
(   '2011-02-01 17:59:59.410')
```

i have got days count from DaysTaken table Now i need to Substract days from Holidays table.For Example daystaken table have 122 days in that days 
3 days holidays till present date came from holidays table.So i need to minus the result and Show 119 Days

Comment: what's wrong with this question getting minus

Comment: please check the question carefully i have already got count of days but how to minus holidays @StanislovasKalašnikovas

Comment: Should it be 120, since there are only 2 holidays from `2015 -03-02` to current date.

Answer (score 1):

Will this do:

```
DECLARE @minDate AS DATE
SELECT @minDate = MIN(Createddate) FROM @Daystaken;

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @minDate, GETDATE()) - COUNT(*) FROM @holiday
WHERE
    CAST(holiday AS DATE) >= @minDate
    AND CAST(holiday AS DATE) <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

---

Here is another one that does not make use of any variable and can be turned easily into an ITVF:

```
WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b),
Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @minDate, GETDATE()))
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
),
CteMinDate(minDate) AS(
    SELECT CAST(MIN(CreatedDate) AS DATE) FROM @Daystaken
)
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM Tally t
CROSS JOIN CteMinDate md
WHERE
    DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, md.minDate) <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM @holiday
        WHERE  CAST(holiday AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, md.minDate)
    )
```